# Hollyoaks Later filming style

Tags: film-techniques, hollyoaks

Having watched Hollyoaks later this week I've noticed that it is filmed in a different style to regular Hollyoaks.

Some colours seem washed out but others seem very vibrant, I was just wondering what they do to achieve this effect.

Hollyoaks

[image]

Hollyoaks Later

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference may be accounted for by the camera setup. *Hollyoaks* is filmed with a [single camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollyoaks), and *Hollyoaks Later* is filmed with [multiple cameras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollyoaks_Later). From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-camera_setup), with a multiple camera set-up,

> ...multiple shots are obtained in a single take without having to
>   start and stop the action. This is more efficient for programs that
>   are to be shown a short time after being shot as it reduces the time
>   spent film editing or video editing the footage...Drawbacks include a
>   less optimized lighting which needs to provide a compromise for all
>   camera angles and less flexibility in putting the necessary equipment
>   on scene, such as microphone booms and lighting rigs.

According to this an [interview](http://primetime.unrealitytv.co.uk/hollyoaks-later-neil-newbon-walker-teases-dark-plot-exclusive-interview-and-pictures/) with actor Neil Newbon (Walker), the single camera gives *Hollyoak* its dramatic feel:

> Hollyoaks is still the only soap that shoots with only one camera, we
>   don’t use multiple camera shots across one another, and we shoot like
>   a drama and because of that we are unique, it has more of a dramatic
>   angle.

With single camera, every time the camera has to be moved, the lighting people have time to set the lights just the way they want them.

Comment: That's great thank you. Your answer does seem to suggest that the filming on Hollyoaks is better than Hollyoaks Later however Hollyloaks later seems to have a better quality. Is this just down to lighting and style, perhaps as Hollyoaks later is more dark and gritty?

Answer (score 1):

It's really just a case of different use of colour timing/correction - that's all, just an artistic decision that's implemented during editing by the tweaks they set when rendering the output files.